# Why are the inferred F# types on these two definitions different in regards to IComparable and comparison?

Tags: f#

Working in F# and having trouble understanding the difference in the following two items:

```
type A<'k, 'v when 'v : comparison and 'k : comparison> = 
    { Keys: Map<'v, 'k> } with 
        member this.length = Map.count this.Keys
module A =
    let empty = { Keys = Map.empty }

type B<'k, 'v when 'v : comparison and 'k : comparison>(keys: Map<'v, 'k>) =
    member __.length = Map.count keys
module B =
    let empty = new B<'k, 'v>(Map.empty)
```

If I look at the inferred types of A.empty and B.empty, I get the following:

```
val empty : A<'a,'b> (requires comparison and comparison)
val empty : B<System.IComparable,System.IComparable>
```

Why are they different? Both 'k and 'v are both being assigned to an F# Map, and are being used in the same way. The only difference is the "new" keyword on B, but why would that change the types inferred for the Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `B.empty` case, you have a let-bound value where you introduce type parameters `'k` and `'v` on the right side without referring to them on the left side. The type inference mechanism then fails to automatically generalize `empty` and instead assigns a specific type to it.

If you try using it in different instantiations, you'll see the second one failing:

```
let t1 : B<int, string> = B.empty 
let t2 : B<string, int> = B.empty // <- getting a type mismatch here.
```

This is due to a property of type inference mechanism called value restriction. [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/) has a good in-depth description of it, including the very case you're looking at right now, implementing `empty` for a generic container type.

In short - `B.empty` can't be generalized here because the expression on the right hand side doesn't produce a value that is easily identifiable as immutable, and as such the compiler errs on the side of caution and decides not to generalize the type of `empty`.

On the other hand, `A.empty` on the right hand side has an expression creating an instance of an immutable record, which is one of the rare scenarios that meet requirements for automatic generalization.

Some ways to avoid it:

- Making `empty` a function:

  ```
  let empty () = new B<'k, 'v>(Map.empty)
  ```
- Putting explicit type arguments on it:

  ```
  let empty<'k, 'v when 'v : comparison and 'k : comparison> = new B<'k, 'v>(Map.empty)
  ```

Comment: The reason why the let-bound value gets assigned a specific type rather than a generic type is another example of the *value restriction* popping up: functions can be generic but values can't, so the let-bound value gets assigned a specific type. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/ for more details, including why the `let empty<'k, 'v> = ...` example works (summary: it still looks like a value, but it's become a kind of function, where the types are the parameters).

Comment: @rmunn: thanks, that's a good blog post, I've edited the answer to include it. I felt it would be related to value restriction, but I didn't see the ever-friendly error message when I was looking at the code in FSI.